# embedXcode template for xCode, does not highlight the code

Tags: xcode, arduino

[image]

I'm trying to code for Arduino board using embedXcode which is a template written for xCode. But I can't see code highlighting or code completion for this file. Does anybody know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you build the project once? During the first build, embedXcode prepares the project to allow code-sense.

For more details, please refer to the chapter • section **Create a New Project • Prepare the Project** on the [User Manual](http://embedxcode.weebly.com/tutorial.html).